# How to add timepicker into a sharedPreference and textView in Kotlin, because the sharedPreferences and textview always showing current time?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-timepicker

So I made this timepicker inside alertdialog using Kotlin.
the time picker is showing but my textview display current time as well as the sharedPreferences instead of selectedTime. I've tried everything, but I don't where can I find the problem. Please, kindly help me out, thank you in advance
Here's my method to show time picker :

```
private fun showTimePicker() {
        var calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = context?.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)!!
        var hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        var minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
        val timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(context, object : TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
            override fun onTimeSet(timepicker: TimePicker?, hourSelected: Int, minuteSelected: Int) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourSelected)
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteSelected)
                var editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()
                editor.putInt("hours", hour)
                editor.putInt("minutes", minute)
                Log.d(PREFS_NAME,"Hour " + hour + " Minute " + minute)
                editor.commit()
            }
        }, hour, minute, false)

        timePickerDialog.show()
        if (!mNotified) {
            NotificationUtils().setNotification(mNotification, context as Activity)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `but my textview` which textview ? am i just not seeing something ?

Comment: sorry, for the textview I tried in another activity, in here the case is using Log.d, I use this log to see if the hour and minute are correct. @a_local_nobody

Answer (score 0):

It's your silly mistake. As you are storing current *hour* and *minute* in *SharedPreference*

```
editor.putInt("hours", hour)
editor.putInt("minutes", minute)
```

You must change it with

```
editor.putInt("hours", hourSelected)
editor.putInt("minutes", minuteSelected)
```